# What does "quite as ... as" mean in the two sentences?

Tags: adverbs

Here are sentences from *The Marvelous Land of Oz* and *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*:

> The child had no playmates, so he did not know that boys often dig out the inside of a "pumpkin-jack," and in the space thus made put a lighted candle to render the face more startling; but he conceived an idea of his own that promised to be **quite as effective**.
>
> They very soon came upon a Gryphon, lying fast asleep in the sun. 'Up, lazy thing!' said the Queen, 'and take this young lady to see the Mock Turtle [...]'; and she walked off, leaving Alice alone with the Gryphon. Alice did not quite like the look of the creature, but on the whole she thought it would be **quite as safe to stay with it as** to go after that savage Queen: so she waited.

OALD gives three relevant definitions of *[quite](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/quite)*:

1. to some degree (British English)
2. to the greatest possible degree
3. to a great degree; very; really

I believe the first meaning doesn't fit the context, but I can't decide which of the last two should be used and how. Can they both mean *much more effective* and *much safer* respectively?

I guess so because of the fact that there are phrases like *twice as ... as*, and I think we can just put *quite* in the place of the *twice* but kind of keep the way the *twice* modifies the adjective between the *as*'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentences provided "quite as" means "to some degree."

As a basic guideline:

"Quite" on its own tends to use the American English definitions you provided. For example:

He is quite a jerk. *(To a great degree, he's a jerk)*

"Quite as" tends to use the British English definition you provided. For example:

She's pretty, but not quite as pretty as the other girls. *(She's pretty, but to some degree not as pretty as the other girls).*